# Unable to call method via primefaces commandButton

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, primefaces

Whenever I bind a method to a primefaces commandButton the method is apparently recognized as a property and a propertyNotFoundException will be thrown.

My guess is that this could be due to the  not being recognized and therefor being translated into plain html, which causes the method to be read as a property. If this is the case, I have been unable to find a solution.

Note: Simply forwarding to a page by primefaces commandButton works perfectly fine of course.

```
xhtml code extract
<h:form>
<p:commandButton action="#{sessionBean.logout}" value="logout" update="loginForm" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Object sessionUser;

public SessionBean() {

}

public String logout() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    return "login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}

public void setSessionUser(Object user) {
   HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
   session.setAttribute("sessionUser", user);
}

public Object getSessionUser() {
   HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
   return session.getAttribute("sessionUser");
}

}
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Property 'logout' not found on type mbeans.SessionBean
javax.faces.FacesException: Property 'logout' not found on type mbeans.SessionBean
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:141)
at     javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'logout' not found on type mbeans.SessionBean
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:214)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:325)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:217)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:157)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CommentInstruction.write(CommentInstruction.java:77)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:207)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
... 18 more

Jan 06, 2014 11:03:43 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: JSF1073: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Property 'logout' not found on type mbeans.SessionBean
Jan 06, 2014 11:03:43 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: Property 'logout' not found on type mbeans.SessionBean
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'logout' not found on type mbeans.SessionBean
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:214)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:325)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:217)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:157)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CommentInstruction.write(CommentInstruction.java:77)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:207)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

As for my project: I am using a maven project with JSF, primefaces 4.0 and JPA 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `#{sessionBean.logout}` it looks for the property `logout` in your `SessionBean`. However in your implementation, `logout` is a method and not a property. Therefore remember to add parenthesis `()` to indicate that it is a method and not a property.
Change your code to:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{sessionBean.logout()}" value="logout" update="loginForm" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I was confused by the fact that JSF does not require parentheses on method calls.